# show strings in compiled binary

Tags: c, string, gcc

Lets suppose I have simple C program and I compile it with `gcc -o hello hello.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

Now I want to display "strings" with the `strings` utility:

```
$ strings hello
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
__gmon_start__
libc.so.6
printf
__libc_start_main
GLIBC_2.2.5
fffff.
l$ L
t$(L
|$0H
hello
;*3$"
```

and, as expected, I can see the string "hello" in the binary.

However, when I modify my `C` program and put "hello" as a constant:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char s[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0' } ;

main()
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

I don't see the string "hello" in the binary anymore.

Can somebody please explain why ?

Comment: Check the *sections* of your executable. [`man strings`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings) suggests "it only prints the strings from  the  initialized  and loaded
       sections  of  object  files".

Comment: More details are required.  It Works For Me (tm) with gcc 4.9.2 on 64-bit Linux.  You may also get a better hint as to why by looking at the assembler output (`gcc -S`) instead of the compiled binary.

Comment: Try `strings -a hello`

Comment: @Jongware - I understand that I just pointed out that it wasn't a constant.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: It Works for me.. which architecture, compiler are you using?

Comment: @Milind - I am using `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2` and `binutils 2.22-8+deb7u2`. My OS is Debian 64-bit

Comment: May be stupid idea... but try running `strings hello |grep "hello$"` just incase its connected to some other string

Comment: Got this on Ubuntu 14.04, GCC 4.8.1 `/lib/ld-linux.so.2
libc.so.6
_IO_stdin_used
printf
__libc_start_main
__gmon_start__
GLIBC_2.0
PTRh
[^_]
hello
;*2$"
hello
`

Comment: "However, when I modify my C program and put "hello" as a constant:" - just fyi, `char s[6] = .... ` isn't constant. And just for interest, move `s` *inside* of `main()` and repeat your test. And it would be ammunition in your question if you added the assembly output as requested, which will denote the segment names.

Comment: Does it work if you try `char str[] = "hello";`?

Comment: The only reasons I could comprehend are 1) array elements would be aligned on a 2/4/8-bytes word, having still `sizeof(s[i]) == 2/4/8` and `sizeof(s)` would be 12/24/48. 2) data segment is stored compressed in the binary. Just suggestions, as the OP result is very surprising...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`man 1 strings`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
>          sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given
>          with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.
>          **By default, it only prints the strings from the initialized and
>          loaded sections of object files**; for other types of files, it prints
>          the strings from the whole file.

The C language does not define strings as first-class citizens. They are *expressed* as either *string arrays* or *strings literals*. For instance, in such basic program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "my string";

    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

we can reasonably say that `s` array holds a string. Notice that this one is allocated on stack. It has *automatic storage duration*, as opposite to example in your question, where `s` is clearly defined outside of `main` (and any) function.

Now, backing to your question, both underlying *objects* in your two programs share the same characteristics:

- they are of type `char[6]` and have the same content (C11 §6.2.5/p20),
- they have *static storage duration*, meaning that they must be initialized conceptually before program's execution (C11 §5.1.2/p1).

The only difference is that modyfing a string literal invokes *undefined behaviur*, thus compiler may choose to place them into seperate (e.g. read-only) memory location.

#### C11 §6.2.5/p20 *Types*:

> An array type describes a **contiguously allocated** nonempty set of
>   objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.

#### C11 §5.1.2/p1 *Execution environments*:

> All objects with static storage duration **shall be initialized** (set to
>   their initial values) before program startup.

Looking from more practical viewpoint, beside that `strings` command you might also analyze your programs with `gdb` debugger, more specifically using `x/s` command. Here is basic illustration:

```
$ gcc -g hello.c -o hello
$ gdb -q hello
Reading symbols from /home/grzegorz/hello...done.
(gdb) disas /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
6   {
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004c5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp

7       printf("%s\n", s);
   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>: mov    $0x60086c,%edi
   0x00000000004004cd <+9>: callq  0x4003b8 <puts@plt>

8   }
   0x00000000004004d2 <+14>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004004d3 <+15>:    retq   

End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/s 0x60086c
0x60086c <s>:    "hello"
```

You might want to compare results of `disas` command for your programs and see if there is some discrepancy between them.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, due to a recent vulnerability in the BFD library, the default for `strings` has been changed in many distributions from `-d` to `-a`, so now the whole file is scanned by default, not only the initialized, loaded sections.

Comment: @rodrigo: Replying to myself, here is a link to the [vulnerability description](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/Oct/112).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see the string "hello" in the binary anymore.

I'd consider this <strike>expected</strike> valid behaviour, as you aren't providing the literal `"hello"` anymore, but 6 seperate `char` literals instead.

Comment: But all of us othen than him see it. Even if they are `char` they are stored consecutively. And visible in `strings`

Comment: I also see them (using a recent Debian stable). However there is not rule they need to be stored consecutively by the compiler. @Milind

Comment: @alk indeed, it's perfectly possible that the compiler might generate a sequence of individual immediate store operations (one for each character).  Without the ASM output we can't tell.